# Generation of different sequence of random numbers that are normally distributed in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I was trying to generate random numbers that are normally distributed. I use the random header for c++11 and I got the random numbers but the same sequence is maintained whenever I execute the program. The question is how can I obtain different sequence anytime I execute the program? This is my code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
complex<double> finding[10];
complex<double> com_one(rand(), rand());
complex<double> com_two(rand(), rand());

mt19937 mt(1729);
normal_distribution<float>dist(0,1);
for(int i = 0; i<16; ++i){
cout << dist(mt)<<", ";
}
cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    complex<double> com_three(rand(), rand());
    finding[i]= com_three;
}
for (int i =0; i<10;i++){
    cout <<"no "<<i<<" element of the finding array is: ";
    cout <<finding[i]<< endl;
}

cout << "The first complex number is" << endl;
cout << com_one.real() << "+" << com_one.imag()
      << "i" << endl;
```

Comment: [`mt19937 mt(1729);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/mersenne_twister_engine) use a different seed!

Comment: Okay but can you suggest a seed for me to use please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the same sequence because you initialize the engine with the same seed here:

```
mt19937 mt(1729); // 1729 is the seed
```

You need to find a way to set a different seed whenever you want a different sequence. How to do this depends on the desired behaviour of your code. You could read it in from the command line, a config file, or generate it from a non-deterministic random device if you don't care about reproducibility (see for example [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).)

Comment: I tried using random_device but whenever I execute it the program crashes.

Comment: @AbubakarSaniAli You must be doing something wrong then.

Comment: #include <random>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    random_device rd;   // non-deterministic generator
    mt19937 gen(rd());  // to seed mersenne twister.
                        // replace the call to rd() with a
                        // constant value to get repeatable
                        // results.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << gen() << " "; // print the raw output of the generator.
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
    }

Comment: @AbubakarSaniAli That looks fine. There must be a problem elsewhere. Or your standard library is broken. Anyway, that is a different question.

Comment: mt19937 mt(time(NULL));